# How to copy multiple rows from VisualVM's CPU Sampler results?

Tags: visualvm

I identified the root cause of a performance issue in VisualVM. I need to put together a report with the data from VisualVM. However, I want to be able to copy and paste multiple rows. Using Shift+Up/Down only selects one row. If you try this in other applications like excel, multiple rows will be selected.

For example to copy and paste these three rows, I needed right click on each row, Copy->Copy Row. Cmd+C does not work because it only gives me method+class. Unfortunately have I dozens of rows to copy.

```
MySlowCode.slowMethod ()    37,576 ms (49.1%)   82.7 ms (3%)
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall ()   37,576 ms (49.1%)   82.7 ms (3%)
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.waitAndDrain () 37,494 ms (49%) 0.0 ms (0%)
```

Details about my environment:

```
VisualVM 1.4.4
MacOS 10.14.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-pasting of multiple lines is currently not supported. However you can take snapshot of collected results and you can then export it to the file. It is possible to export it as .csv, .html, .xml.